# Timing not met for Rocket core (RISC V)

Tags: riscv

Ran synthesis and implementation for ROCKET CHIP (using Vivado).
RTL files were generated using the default config.This includes FPU also.

Lot of timing violations are seen.This violations are mostly coming from FPU.
Even after regenerating the RTL without FPU, still violations are seen.

We are targeting it for 500 Mhz. As per RISC-V org 1Ghz is achievable.

Are there any timing constraints available for same.

Apart from the below constraint file.
fpga-zynq/zc706/src/constrs/base.xdc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your flow is not retiming the FPU. Your tools need to retime the FPU - it is described combinationally and then pads out the latency with registers.