# How to make verilog is ready for CAD tools after build the VCS simulator

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I've built the VCS simulator successfully with some configuration (Default, DualCoreConfig, RoCCExampleConfig etc.) and get the desire files under vism/generated-src
Now How Can I use/prepare this file to in CAD-tools (SYNOPSIS)

Do I need any processing to compile the Verilog file to run in CAD tools or how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: I think "CAD" is referring to "computer aided design", not a specific tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation about this on the [Rocket Chip README](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip#-3-pushing-a-rocket-core-through-the-vlsi-tools).

You primarily need to do two things:

1. Populate any memory blackboxes. You can either modify the included `scripts/vlsi_mem_gen` script to align with your memory compiler (or the memories generated by your memory compiler) or manually populate this blackbox. You can find the parameters of the blackboxed memories in a `vsim/generated_src/*.conf` file.
2. Run VCS with the `SYNTHESIS` variable defined.

If building Rocket Chip with the "hardfloat" floating point unit, you should enable retiming in your VLSI tools to get a decent clock rate (as indicated by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39006952/3870549).